# How to use custom table as auth table instead user table?

Tags: authentication, laravel-5, tablename

I am beginner of Laravel 5.3.
What i want is to use custom table as auth table instead user table.
Because user table should be used for other purpose.
How can I edit config/auth.php or other thing?
Please help me!

file auth.php

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session", "token"
    |
    */

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Admin::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],

];
```

file Admin.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Admin as Authenticatable;

class Admin extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `auth.php` change `providers.users.model` to your custom class.

Like:

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\NewUser::class,
    ],
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#introduction-database-considerations)

**Update**

In your `Admin.php` file change

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Admin as Authenticatable;
```

to

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
```

Comment: Sorry, it doen't work with error "Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Admin' not found"

Comment: Is your custom table name is `admin`? If yes then can you show your updated `auth.php` and `Admin.php` file in your question.

Comment: oh, that error disappeard but they say I have to create admins table,
before I created admin table. Do i have to rename it?
Why laravel think admins table as auth table instead of admin table?
what about "s" suffix?

Comment: By convention, the "snake case", plural name of the class will be used as the table name unless another name is explicitly specified. It is great to follow conventions so you can change the table name to `admins`. Otherwise, you can read the docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions) to change the table name.

Comment: Great! I tried to find answer googling a lot, but never find right answer.
How can I ever thank you!

Comment: Glad to help! You should read the documentation thoroughly, it will help you a lot in long run. If possible please upvote the answer, it helps me to answer more questions.